# NetSuite Script 2.0 how to disable the Amount field on the Line Item, on the Quotation Form

Tags: netsuite

Is there a way to disable the line item field Amount?

Currently the Amount field is visible, and users can basically edit the Amount if they wish.  The finance requested that the Fiedl Amount on the Quotation Form (“Estimate”) should be disable to prevent Sales Rep from change the Amount.

If click the Customize form and view the Sublist Field Amount, there is NO Option to disable the field.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to either just not show it on the form, in the columns (not a secure way of avoiding the issue).  Or, you can script the field to be disabled when it it loaded on the form.

Comment: HI, the Finance prefer it to be Disable. But how to script the Amount field to be Disabled? Can you give Script for it to be Disabled? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You should create a client script :

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType ClientScript
*/
define(['N/record'],
    function (record) {
        function lineInit(context) {
            try {
                /** this will disable the amount for existing line */
                var rec = context.currentRecord;
                var itemCount = rec.getLineCount('item');
                var sublistName = context.sublistId;
                var line = rec.getCurrentSublistIndex({ sublistId: sublistName });
                if (itemCount > line) {
                    var theField = rec.getSublistField({
                        sublistId: sublistName,
                        fieldId: 'amount',
                        line: line
                    });
                    theField.isDisabled = true;
                }
                /** this will hide the amount label for the new line : inspect the tag ID input#amount_formattedValue*/
                if (!document.getElementById('hidden-amount-style')) {
                    var css = 'input#amount_formattedValue { display: none; }',
                        head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
                        style = document.createElement('style');
                    head.appendChild(style);
                    style.type = 'text/css';
                    style.id = 'hidden-amount-style';
                    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(' lineInit', JSON.stringify(e, null, 4));
            }
        }
        function pageInit(context) { }
        function validateField(context) { return true; }
        function fieldChanged(context) { }
        function postSourcing(context) { }
        function lineInit(context) { }
        function validateDelete(context) { return true; }
        function validateInsert(context) { return true; }
        function validateLine(context) { return true; }
        function sublistChanged(context) { }
        function saveRecord(context) { return true }
        return {
            pageInit: pageInit,
            fieldChanged: fieldChanged,
            postSourcing: postSourcing,
            sublistChanged: sublistChanged,
            lineInit: lineInit,
            validateField: validateField,
            validateLine: validateLine,
            validateInsert: validateInsert,
            validateDelete: validateDelete,
            saveRecord: saveRecord,
        };
    });
```